# base64 data not displaying image from base64_encode

Tags: php, base64, lumen

I'm trying to convert an image to base64 from an external source, below is my attempt

```
$imgsrc = file_get_contents('mydomain.com/assets/img/logo.png');

return response()->json([ 'img' => base64_encode($imgsrc) ]);
```

and below is the output,

> data:image/png;base64,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

but on `<img>` tag, its not rendering.

Comment: Please investigate your Base64 encoded data.  When I decode it I get HTML markup not image data.

Comment: 1) If you remove the 'data:image/png;base64,', and base64 decode it, does it decode into the original file? 2) What errors come out in the browser's console. 3) Inspecting the web page, is the image tag there, if yes does it reflect the expected data?

Comment: Missing `$` before `imgsrc`, *that* line should be `return response()->json([ 'img' => base64_encode($imgsrc) ]);`. By the way, how are you rendering the encoded image in `<img>` tag?

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul updated. my apology for the missing $.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the image, try this

```
$imageData = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD........";//base64_encode strong
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $imageData . '" />';
```

OR

```
$code_base64 = $row['content'];//base64_encode strong
$code_base64 = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,','',$code_base64);
$code_binary = base64_decode($code_base64);
$image= imagecreatefromstring($code_binary);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```